Delay window function (including fraction delay value)
Introduction - Context
I am trying to implement some truncated/windowed $\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$ fractional delay. I have managed to get “correct” results (compared to an implementation known to produce correct results). Next, I would like to introduce a windowing function to taper the edges of the truncated sinc filter.
Problem
The problem I am trying to tackle now is to introduce a delay to the windowing function to “match” it (in time) with the delayed sinc function.
Attempt
At the moment, I am dealing with arbitrary delay values, which can be greater than unity. However, I do not split the delay into its integral and fractional parts. I am doing the prototypes in MATLAB and provide some basic code below
idx = (-len + 1:len).'; % Filter sample indices
    
causDel = -floor(idx(1)/2); % The delay required for the filter to become causal
sincFilt = sinc(idx - delay); % The filter

% Keep only the central part of the filter to match the length asked for
sincFilt = sincFilt(causDel + 1:causDel + len);

where len is the desired length of the FIR filter and del is the desired delay in samples (integral + fractional part - e.g. $7.8 \textrm{ samps}$). Below is an example filter acquired in this way for len = 16 and del = 3.25.

This is where I am kind of stuck. I have attempted to calculate a raised-cosine (Hann) window by calculating the window at the indices the $sinc$ filter is calculated (given by idx), apply the window to the function and then keep only the part of the filter that is “relevant” but it didn’t really work out. Below is the code that I have used and the result I got.
totDel = causDel + del; % Delay to make the filter causal plus the delay the filter has to apply to the signal

win = sin(pi * (idx - totDel)/len).^2; % Hann filter at the delayed indices
sincFilt = win .* sincFilt;

sincFilt = sincFilt(causDel + 1:causDel + len);
win = win(causDel + 1:causDel + len);


As can be seen in this last figure, the window peaks at the “correct” (desired) position but at the edge, the windowing function exhibits some unwanted behaviour (reaching the other half period of the cosine function). I have tried to change the offsets but then the window does not peak at the maximum of the delayed sinc function.
The same behaviour is seen with the Hamming windowing function. Although I haven’t tried any other windows I believe that the same issue would arise.
Any input would be most welcome.

Are you trying to use a windowed $\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$ function to accomplish precision delay (delay with a continuous-time precision, or at least a precision that is better than the original sample time)?  I think what you want is an oversampled, windowed-$\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$ function.  I don't think that you want to do what it appears that you're asking for.  Just center the window function over the centered $\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$ function.

I can send you some MATLAB code to help you get good coefficients for an adjustable fractional delay.  Just send me an email.  You can find my email address by just googling me.  (Just go to the W3 version of the Cookbook to get my email address.)

Hey @robertbristow-johnson, thanks for the comments. I’m not trying to get “continuous-time” precision, but I am trying to get fractional sample delays (well, you could argue that this is indeed “continuous-time” precision, but getting extremely accurate results is not what I’m really after here). I'm not sure why you suggest that the $sinc(\cdot)$ function should be oversampled, but I’ll try to look a bit more into it. I thought that what I am actually doing is indeed centering the window function over the sinc function but I’ll try the “brute-force” approach to see what I can get out of it.

//"I'm not sure why you suggest that the sinc(⋅) function should be oversampled,"// . . . . . .
Oversample it by a factor of $256$ and you can have coefficients for every multiple of $\frac{1}{256}$ sample.  That's a high degree of precision, better than a 1/2 % of a sample period.  However you design your brickwall filter (and Kaiser-windowed sinc is a very good design), if you can have the precise delay between neighboring multiples of  $\frac{1}{256}$ sample, you can linearly interpolate between these adjacent sub-samples and lose nearly nothing in precision.

Okay, for the formal breakdown.  The integer component tells you which $L$ adjacent samples that are linearly combined and the fractional part tells you what the $L$ coefficients are to combine the samples.  That's how you do polyphase fractional delay.  You get two adjacent fractional samples, and then you linearly interpolate between them.  Easy and nearly perfect fractional delay.

Thanks a bunch again @robertbristow-johnson. I’ll have a better look into it. At the moment, I have aligned the window to the peak of the $\textrm{sinc}(\cdot)$ function, and it seems to be working reasonably well. I’ll have to run some simulations to see whether the results are adequate for the work at hand, but I’ll definitely look more into your suggestion (either for the current or future work). I’ll update the question accordingly. P.S.: Oversampling does make much sense, and I understand that interpolating between samples (after oversampling) provides a very good approximation.

//"At the moment, I have aligned the window to the peak of the sinc(⋅) function"// - - - - - - - - - - That's the correct way to do it.  Read my long post with all of the math.  Precision delay is a solved problem, both theoretically and practically.

Yes, this is what I am going through now, and it kind of looks like what I have done, too, albeit you have provided some mathematical justification with some formulas that are quite easy to implement. I’ll compare what I have with your solution (and my code will be corrected accordingly) tomorrow as it is a wee bit late here. Thanks a bunch for the help. Since an answer is already available on this SE, I may think of deleting the question altogether.

Required reading for any fractional delay work is https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/482137. All source code is still available at http://legacy.spa.aalto.fi/software/fdtools/  Unless you have highly unusual requirements I doubt you can do better than that.

Aaahhh yes, the code from these people. I had forgotten it is still available, thanks for the reminder @Hilmar. I'm sure this will be adequate (I'm not after some crazy high quality algorithms anyway. I'm pretty sure this codebase and the info from Robert will be more than enough to get me rolling.
